# Can you !important a whole css file?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using Jquery ui on my university's website but they are using Serena Collage with prebuilt templates with their own styles.

The widget im using works in firefox but not ie7, which is kind of buggy.

The mater template's css is obviously the culprit.

How do I !important the Jquery UI css file or easily !important a whole style.

Comment: If everything is important then nothing is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't. `!important` is set on a per property basis (and its enough of a sledgehammer that it is best avoided there, let alone globally).

Write your selectors so they are more specific.

Comment: Good point. You should always be able to write specific-enough CSS selectors.

Comment: the Jquery lies within the main body of the template. I dont think I have access to the main templates css files. I can only create and edit styles in the main body.

Am I out of luck?

Comment: Your inline styles will override the stylesheet unless the entry in the stylesheet is marked !important

Comment: sorry guys. it's not the css styles. the page ended up having two DOCTYPES HTML and XHTML. I deleted one and it worked.